# Why have they used function strdup in K&R section 6.5?

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

In *The C Programming Language* by KNR - 2nd edition, section 6.5 they have defined a function `strdup` thus:

```
char *strdup(char *s)
{
   char *p;

   p = (char *) malloc(strlen(s) + 1) /* +1 for the '\0' */
   if (p != NULL)
     strcpy(p, s);
   return p;
}
```

The usage is to copy a string onto a member of a structure `tnode` defined thus:

```
struct tnode {
char *word;
int count;
struct tnode *left;
struct tnode *right;
};
```

Called like this:

```
struct tnode *addtree(struct tnode *p, char *w)
{
...
p->word = strdup(w);
...
}
```

Why cannot we instead use something like this?

```
strcpy(p->word, w);
```

Comment: You need to have done the malloc() that the strdup function does somewhere before you can use strcpy into a character pointer variable. word has to be pointing to valid memory. When first instantiate it, it could be pointing anywhere.

Comment: Where do you think that is copying *to*? "copy a string onto a member of a structure" -- no, that's not what it's doing ... that member is a pointer, not an array.

Comment: @Scooter Essentially, I wanted to know the reason behind an explicit allocation through malloc(). I was(am) under the impression that a declaration of a pointer parameter also allocates memory for the relevant data type.

Comment: @Jim Balter - um... It was just a way of saying, keeping in mind the end result... of having a string being pointed at by the member ultimately.

Comment: @captainsomewhere Nope, the declaration of a pointer does not do any implicit allocation of memory for it to point to. The programmer has to do it explicitly.

Comment: @Jim Balter - um... roger that. But in the definition for addtree(struct tnode *p, char *w), struct tnode *p is a parameter (or argument) right? I believed that this would allocate an amount of memory equal to that required by a tnode type of structure.. and p would point to that allocation. What's a field again? You mean a member? KNR hasn't mentioned 'field' so far...

Comment: Yes, a field is a member (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720142/programming-terms-field-member-properties-c). And thinking that a function parameter can somehow allocate memory is just bizarre; it makes no sense at all. You're passing in a pointer to the memory, not requesting that memory be allocated and have its address stuck into wherever the pointer came from. And again, how much memory? Pointers can point to either individual items or to arrays. P.S. A parameter is a variable declared in a function prototype. An argument is the value at the call site assigned to the parameter.

Comment: @Jim Balter - It just... seemed plausible. Overlooked the fact that pointers can point to variable length objects. TY for... pointing that out. Wish K&R had a section on how and when memory is allocated though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If to use "something like"

```
strcpy(p->word, w);
```

then the program will have undefined behaviour because 1) p->word was not initialized and have any unspecified value; and 2) this statement is trying to write to a memory that was not allocated.

If you will allocate memory and initialize p->word with the valid address of the memory and then use "something like"

```
strcpy(p->word, w);
```

then in fact you will write the same realization of `strdup` yourself.

Comment: So if addtree were to receive the structure itself instead of a pointer to the structure, would "something like that" have worked?

Comment: @captainsomewhere If for example the structure  would have a character array large enough that to keep passed as argument a string then you could simply copy the argument to the array.

Comment: @captainsomewhere: it is *independent* of whether the `char *` is inside a structure or not. It has nothing to do with the structure itself.

Comment: @captainsomewhere No, that wouldn't work, because the structure itself *still* doesn't provide memory for what word points to. And passing the structure itself and then storing into it would just store into a temporary stack location, and the changes would be lost when the function returned. You have been told repeatedly that a pointer, such as `word`, doesn't point to anything until you set it to point to something ... you need to start listening.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to allocate memory for `p->word` then you can use `strcpy(p->word, w);` as `word` is a `char` pointer and no memory is allocated to it before.

So if you call `strcpy(p->word, w);` without allocating memory, it will cause [Undefined behavior.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: Roger. Can't up-vote, not enough reputation. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @captainsomewhere: No worries captain :) I hope you understand the situation ;)